# How do I manage my memory better when using the Map function?

Tags: list-manipulation, memory, map

So I'm attempting to write a Mathematica program that prints a range of natural numbers as the sum of four cubes. I wrote the following Mathematica code to try this, but am running into a memory constraint.

```
SumOfFourCubesSolver[start_, end_, k_] := Block[
   {
    i = 0,
    slimmedlist = {},
    slimmedslimmedlist = {}
    },
   Share[
    $HistoryLength = 0;
    ClearSystemCache[];
    slimmedlist = 
     Select[Flatten[
       Outer[List, Range[-k, k], Range[-k, k], Range[-k, k], 
         Range[-k, k]]^3, 3], Total[#] >= start && Total[#] <= end &];
    slimmedslimmedlist = 
     DeleteDuplicates[slimmedlist, Total[#1] == Total[#2] &];
    f[x_] := Module[{}, Print[Total[x], ":", CubeRoot[x]]; i++];
    Map[f, slimmedslimmedlist];
    Print[MemoryInUse[]];
    ];
   Print[i];
   ];
```

I have tried replacing Module with Block, Clearing System Cache, and setting history length to 0, but nothing seems to work. Once the data sets gets larger, I usually get an error message saying "The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation". I am not looking for an answer, but just a step in the right direction or some material I can read up on to fix this myself. Below this is the output when the k value is 2, start is 1, and end is 300:

7:{-2,-1,2,2}

1:{-2,0,1,2}

8:{-2,0,2,2}

2:{-2,1,1,2}

9:{-2,1,2,2}

16:{-2,2,2,2}

5:{-1,-1,-1,2}

6:{-1,-1,0,2}

14:{-1,-1,2,2}

15:{-1,0,2,2}

23:{-1,2,2,2}

3:{0,1,1,1}

10:{0,1,1,2}

17:{0,1,2,2}

24:{0,2,2,2}

4:{1,1,1,1}

11:{1,1,1,2}

18:{1,1,2,2}

25:{1,2,2,2}

32:{2,2,2,2}

43664064

20

I have tried using a k value of 50, which crashes my computer, and with a k value of higher, say 150, I get the error message as stated above. Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a start would be to use `Scan` instead of `Map`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

This ran fine on a beat-up old loungebook with k=100...

(BTW - this does not directly answer the "How do I fix this problem doing things this way..." aspect - sometimes the answer is just "...don't do it that way..." when there's a more direct path to the desired results.)

```
k = 100;
size = 4;
start = 1;
end = 300;
howmany = 1;

If[howmany =!= All, Off[IntegerPartitions::take]];

result = Table[{n, 
     Surd[IntegerPartitions[n, {size}, Range[-k, k]^3, howmany], 
      3]}, {n, start, end}]; 

On[IntegerPartitions::take];
```

Results are in symbol `result`, a table of the `n` and corresponding values that when cubed and sum are `n`.

`size` is how many (4 in your case) per solution element.
`start` and `end` are self-evident.
`howmany` determines how many solutions to present (at most) per `n` - use All for all of them.

The `On` and `Off` enable/suppress the message generated when the requested number cannot be found.

n.b. - If you find yourself interested in solutions of this type limited to positive elements, the built-in `PowersRepresentations` is your friend...